# IndexError: list index out of range while accessing data from list inside a dictionary

Tags: python

I am struggling with the error:

```
in <module>
    q_sol = data_d['q_sol'][idx1][idx2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am trying to draw a plot between `q_sol` and `cl_sol` but somehow not able to understand these indexing thing correctly.
I am new to python. I would be great if can be helped in resolving this error.

```
The value of data_d= {'num_qubits': [3], 'obj_count': [[0]], 'circ_count': [[3372]], 'iter_count': [[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]], 'err': [[9.622750520686739e-05]], 'params': [[array([ 6.77857446,  8.45117651,  5.98536102,  6.77631199,  4.42401965,
            8.78988251,  6.30550002, 10.77596014, 12.7089123 ,  4.95594055,
            9.14241059,  5.84989104,  8.40700518, 11.64485529,  0.81896469,
            0.82775066,  0.36833961, 10.27488743, 10.09543112, 10.91158005,
           12.3788683 ,  9.96858319,  5.62269489])]], 'q_sol': [[array([ 0.62855239,  0.90343679,  0.82492677,  0.39294472, -0.39294322,
           -0.82492691, -0.90343593, -0.62855236])]], 'cl_sol': [array([ 0.62853936,  0.90352533,  0.82495791,  0.3928371 , -0.3928371 ,
           -0.82495791, -0.90352533, -0.62853936])]}





def plot_solution_vectors(q_sol, cl_sol):
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(q_sol, label='qauntum', color='black')
    ax.plot(cl_sol, label='classical', color='black', linestyle='dashed')
    ax.legend()
    ax.set_xlabel('Node number')
    ax.set_ylabel('Components of solution')
    
    cnorm = np.linalg.norm(q_sol)
    qnorm = np.linalg.norm(cl_sol)
    
    ax.text(0.55, 0.65, 'Norm (quantum) = %.1f'%(qnorm), transform=ax.transAxes)
    ax.text(0.55, 0.55, 'Norm (classical) = %.1f'%(cnorm), transform= ax.transAxes)
    
    return fig, ax   
                
idx1, idx2 = 3, 0
q_sol = data_d['q_sol'][idx1][idx2]
cl_sol = data_d['cl_sol'][idx1]
plot_solution_vectors(q_sol, cl_sol)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `data_d['q_sol']`, you can see that the value is:

```
[[array(
  [ 0.62855239,  0.90343679,  0.82492677,  0.39294472, -0.39294322,
   -0.82492691, -0.90343593, -0.62855236])]]
```

...so `data_d['q_sol'][0]` is:

```
[array(
  [ 0.62855239,  0.90343679,  0.82492677,  0.39294472, -0.39294322,
   -0.82492691, -0.90343593, -0.62855236])]
```

`data_d['q_sol'][0][0]`:

```
array(
    [ 0.62855239,  0.90343679,  0.82492677,  0.39294472, -0.39294322,
     -0.82492691, -0.90343593, -0.62855236])
```

...and `data_d['q_sol'][0][0][3]` (which I believe is the value you actually want) is:

```
0.39294472
```

Comment: Thank yo explaining the indexing of python. I have to fix the idx1 and idx2 properly as you explained.

Comment: You might also consider just simplifying your `data_d` structure so that, e.g.: `data_d = {... 'q_sol':  [ 0.62855239,  0.90343679,  0.82492677,  0.39294472, -0.39294322, -0.82492691, -0.90343593, -0.62855236], ...}`